# Python while not loop

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I cannot understand the following code:

```
i = 0
j = 0
while not(i < 3 or j == 5):
  i = i + 1
  j = j + 1
print(i)
```

returns 0, even though the inverse (not) of j == 5 returns true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`not(i < 3 or j == 5)`

is equivalent (by [De Morgan's duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) to:

`not(i < 3) and not(j ==5)`

which is further simplified to:

`(i >= 3) and (j != 5)`

so since `i = j  = 0` this condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 6):

```
i < 3 or j == 5
```

returns True (`i<3`) therefore

`not(i < 3 or j == 5)` returns False which means that your while loop does nothing at all and finally your code prints the value of i which is 0

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `not(i<3 or j==5)` corresponds to `(i >= 3 and j != 5)`. Since i and j do not satisfy both of these conditions at the same time, the code does not go into the loop and the variables i and j stay 0.

Answer (score 2):

i = 0 and j = 0, so not(i < 3 or x == 5) = not(0 < 3 or 0 == 5) = not(True or False) = not True = False

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 0
j = 0
while not(i < 3 or j == 5):
  i = i + 1
  j = j + 1
print(i)
```

`(i < 3 or x == 5)` -> `(True or False)` -> `True` -> `not True` -> `False` ->

```
i = 0
j = 0
while False:
  i = i + 1
  j = j + 1
print(i)
```

Also, `(not(i < 3) and not(j == 5))` -> `(False and True)` -> `False`

So it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 2):

`i = 0`
`j = 0`
are the initial values for the variables, then `while not (i < 3 or j == 5)`
is the condition for the loop to initiate, which will only take place if `j` is not less than 3 or if `j` is equal to 5. Which isn't the case since `i=0` and 0<3, and `j` isn't equal to 0.

In other words, the code will skip the loop and print `i`, which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

`while` loop breaks, when its condition doesn't evaluate to `True`. In your case condition is `not(i < 3 or j == 5)`. This means for this loop to break `(i<3 or j==5)` should be `True`. At start both i and j is 0. Then `(i<3 or j==5)` becomes `(True or False)`, then `True`. That's why your loop breaks so early